# Declare Variable from .each Iteration in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to create a method for a self referential relationship that requires two variables to be declared in the controller method...

1) The current record the user is viewing [record = Record.find(params[:parent_id])]

2) The record being selected from a record.each iteration on the primary record's "Show" page as shown below...

```
  <% Record.find_each do |record| %>
    <div>
      <%= record.name %>
    </div>
    <%= form_for(@record.active_relationships.build) do |f| %>
      <div>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :parent_id, record.id %>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit "Follow" %>
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
```

How can this record be declared as a variable in the controller similar to that done with the primary record (1)?

Below is the the method I have in the controller so far...

```
def create
        record = Record.find(params[:parent_id])
        record.follow(record)
        redirect_to record
    end
```

As you will notice there are two instances of record in the second line. the problem I am having is arising in that I am unsure as how to define the second instance of record to reflect objective 2.

Comment: I don't understand your point 2, are you trying to show `Record`'s associations ?

Comment: Essentially I am trying to create a form that allows a user to attach related records to the record the are viewing from a list of all records.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a [select](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease) input

Comment: I think we need the controller method code in order to really answer this.

Comment: I have added the controller method that I am currently using above. I have based this on a method designed for users to follow each other in which the first instance of record in the second line is replaced by current_user. obviously this does not apply here but I believe i need to define a variable that will serve a similar function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the following lines to the form and controller respectively I was able to define the currently viewed record as the child in the self referential relationship thus allowing the relationship to be created between two records...

Form

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :child_id, @ingref.id %>
```

Controller

```
current_ingref = Ingref.find(params[:child_id])
```